# AUTO_increment с 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Как сделать так, чтобы A_I начинался с 0, а не 1 ? Чтобы вместо ID:1,2,3,4 было ID:0,1,2,3

Comment: *Storing 0 into an AUTO_INCREMENT column has the same effect as storing NULL, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled.*

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее, что делает эта команда ? После её ввода просто ничего не меняется.

Comment: @ilya50 назначает с какого числа a_i начнет устанавливать значения, но Вам ответили в комментарии выше более опытный товарищ, mysql сами не рекомендуют назначать a_i 0 потому что он приравнивается к null, если не включена соответствующая настройка. А не меняется, скорее всего потому, что у вас уже есть строки в таблице, в таком случае a_i считает от последней записи

Comment: @ilya50 *После её ввода просто ничего не меняется.* См. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Но при наличии в таблице записей - получите ошибку при попытке ввода новых записей.